# On change of coordinate basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

**Question**

Let
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1\\
-3 & -5 & 0\\
4 & 6 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
-2\\
2\\
3
\end{bmatrix},
v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
-8\\
5\\
2
\end{bmatrix},
v_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
-7\\
2\\
6
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Find a basis $\{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $P$ is the change-of-coordinates matrix from $\{u_1, u_2, u_3\}$ to the basis $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$.

**Theorem**

The theorem given in my textbook states the following:

Let $$B = \{b_1, \dots, b_n\}$$ and $$C = \{c_1, \dots, c_n\}$$ be bases of a vector space $V$. There exists a unique $n \times n$ matrix $P$ such that $$\begin{bmatrix} \textbf{x} \end{bmatrix}_C = P\begin{bmatrix} \textbf{x} \end{bmatrix}_B.$$ The columns of $P$ are the $C$-coordinate vectors of the vectors in the basis $B$ and the matrix $P$ is called the change-of-coordinates matrix from $B$ to $C$.

**My working**

Given my understanding of the theorem, I thought that
$$\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 & v_2 & v_3
\end{bmatrix}
= P
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & u_2 & u_3
\end{bmatrix},$$
so we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & u_2 & u_3
\end{bmatrix}
& = P^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 & v_2 & v_3
\end{bmatrix}\\[2 mm]
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
21 & 10 & 11\\
-13 & -7 & -7\\
-3 & 4 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}.$$

**The suggested answer**

If $C$ is the basis $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$, then the columns of $P$ are $[u_1]_C$, $[u_2]_C$ and $[u_3]_C$. Thus, $$u_j = [v_1, v_2, v_3][u_j]_C$$ and
$$\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & u_2 & u_3
\end{bmatrix}
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 & v_2 & v_3
\end{bmatrix}
P\\[2 mm]
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
-6 & -6 & -5\\
-5 & -9 & 0\\
21 & 32 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}.$$

---

I am not sure why my answer is different from the suggested solution. Have I misunderstood the theorem? Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are misunderstanding $[x]_A$. For a vector $x$ and a basis $A$ it denotes the coordinates of $x$ in the basis $A$. For example $[u_1]_B=(1,0,0)$ if $B=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Hello! Thank you for your comment. I understand what you are saying, but I am still not quite sure where I have gone wrong?

Comment: $v_i=Pu_i$ is simply not true and you start from that assumption. What is true is that if you start from say $u_1$ (yet unknown), express its coordinates in the basis $B$ (that will be $(1,0,0)$) and apply $P$ to that (which is basically taking the 1st column of $P$) then you will get the coordinates of $u_1$ in basis $C$.